# Access Gmail Account using IMAPlib in Python 3.6

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.6, imaplib

Here is my code in python 3.6:

```
import imaplib, email, os
from imaplib import *

username = 'username@gmail.com'
password = 'password'

print("Logging into your Gmail Account...")

mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com',993)
mail.login(username,password)
```

While running the above code, I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/imap.py", line 10, in <module>
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com',993)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imaplib.py", line 1283, in __init__
IMAP4.__init__(self, host, port)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imaplib.py", line 197, in __init__
self.open(host, port)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imaplib.py", line 1296, in open
IMAP4.open(self, host, port)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imaplib.py", line 294, in open
self.sock = self._create_socket()
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imaplib.py", line 1286, in _create_socket
sock = IMAP4._create_socket(self)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imaplib.py", line 284, in _create_socket
return socket.create_connection((self.host, self.port))
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\socket.py", line 722, in create_connection
raise err
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\socket.py", line 713, in create_connection
sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

Please help me with the above problem. I have tried many solutions but haven't got an answer. I tried it in python 2.7 but the same problem persists.

Comment: Are you sure your firewall/ISP lets connections to port 993 proceed?

Comment: No, I am not sure. Please guide me through it.